# ScrollView: set some sliding "threshold" before actually scrolling ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview

Here's the idea: I have some ScrollView, e.g. with 10 elements, say buttons.
Only 5 are visible at the time.

By default, if I swipe up a little bit (30% of next element's height), app will show me 30% of 6th item, and hide 30% of 1st item at the top.

I would like to customize this behavior, so that it pulls up a new element from below only after I've swiped up for more than a half of that elements height.

If I swipe just a little, it disregards scrolling and hides back the element that could've been shown if I swiped more.

Sadly, I can't remember an app to point as an example. The nearest is pulling NavigationDrawer (or sliding home screens in your launcher): if you slide only a little and release - it hides everything back.

Additionally, I would animate showing that new element (e.g. scaling from 0 to 100) and hiding the one on top that is being hid (scaling from 100 to 0). But that's second issue, I'd rather think of it when I deal with this threshold of scrolling.

Has anyone heard about some kind of library for this? I would expect that to be in API, but it's not there, AFAIK.

Comment: have you tried onInterceptTouchEvent?

Comment: Nope. Not a line of code has been written yet.
First of all I was wondering if there some ready solution. I didn't found one and asked.
I'll do some other tasks now, if nothing shows up until then, well, I'll have to do it by myself. Maybe by overriding that onInterceptTouchEvent. At least I'll try.

Comment: so you found now something to start with